# Using Python Bulk Data Received From Weighing Scale Is Being Collected Via RS-232 Cable But Only Need a Piece of Data

Tags: python

A novice python programmer facing a challenge.
From attached code below, I am able to read data from the scale onto my console. But would like to be able to just use a portion of the received information (i.e. the number of pieces [PCS]) into a MySQL database.

I have tried creating an array to be able to index it out but still no luck.
I have also tried using a for loop to read items out, but nothing displays on console then.
NB, This would be receiving continuous data from scales.

Attached image for better insight.

Appreciate any suggestions, need it to complete a job on the shop floor.
Many thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvlU6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try:
while True:

```
    weight = ser.readline().decode().strip().replace(' ', '') # take out .strip() and check if it causes bugs, remember this removes trailing chrac i.e \r\n from displaying on console. also try add .split('\r\n') or .split(" ") 
    #val = weight.splitlines()
    #loc = list(map(str, val))
    #arr = np.array(weight)
    #print(val); #Consider using indexing to print or send received data seperatly.
    
    
    pcs_value = re.findall(r'PCS(\d+)', weight)
    
    if len(pcs_value) > 0:
        inpt = int(''.join(pcs_value))
        print(inpt)

        # Check if the value already exists in the table
        
        sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scales WHERE Weight = %s"
        cursor.execute(sql, (inpt,))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        
        if result[0] == 0:
            # If the value does not exist, insert it into the table
            sql = "INSERT INTO scales (Weight) VALUES (%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (inpt,))
            db.commit()
        else:
            print("Value already exists in the table")
    else:
        print("No PCS value found")



    
    
    



"""  
for line in weight:
    if line.startswith("PCS"):
        print(line)
"""
```

finally:
ser.close();

Python Code looks messy, but this seemed to fix my issue so far.
Previous code in image attached to question.

Have fun !!!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).